# How can I remap a point after an image rotation?

Tags: python, opencv, rotation

I have a mathematical question: let's suppose I rotate an image around its center by an angle of 30°, using the opencv with the following commands:

```
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),30,1)
img_rotate = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols,rows))
```

If a take the pixel (40,40) of the img_rotate, how can I know which is the corresponding pixel in the original image?

EDIT: in other words, when I apply the rotation to an image I obtain the transformed image. Is there the possibility to obtain the mapping between points? For example the (x,y) point of the new image corresponds to (x',y') point of the original image.

Comment: Just do the same maths on the coordinate to find the new value?

Comment: I don't understand. Which are the coordinates of the corresponding value of the original image? I need to know how to remap the point (40,40) on the orginal image.

Comment: InverseOfM*point is the mapping you are looking for

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just use matrix operation as described in [Affine Transformations](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html) and inverse matrix.

```
# inverse matrix of simple rotation is reversed rotation.
M_inv = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((100/2, 300/2),-30,1)


# points
points = np.array([[35.,  0.],
                   [175., 0.],
                   [105., 200.],
                   [105., 215.],
                  ])
# add ones
ones = np.ones(shape=(len(points), 1))

points_ones = np.hstack([points, ones])

# transform points
transformed_points = M_inv.dot(points_ones.T).T
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [transform()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#transform) function to apply given transformation to arrays of points.

```
cv2.transform(pointsToTransform, M)
```

Comment: Great! Have I to use M or a modified matrix (I think I have to consider an inverse rotation, so by -30°)?

Comment: It should be same matrix M, as far as I know.

Comment: I'm wrong, I don't think it is the right answer. I need to the coordinates of the corresponding point, not the transformed point.

Comment: you can go in both directions. from original image to new image you use `cv2.transform(coordinateInOriginalImage, M)` and the other way around you use `cv2.transform(coordinateInRotatedImage, M.inverse())`

Comment: I don't know about Python, but in C++ it should be array of points (that may contain just a single point)

Comment: @Alessandro so what is coordinateinOriginalImage? What shape are these?

Comment: cv::Mat has no member inverse()