# Cropping of Aligned face image in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, face-recognition, javacv

How do the cropping of Image is done after face alignment. The reason I'm asking this question is that, the landmarks are used to Align the image and after the alignment is done the old landmarks are not valid anymore for the aligned image. So how can I tightly crop the image to take only the face position. Is it require to calculate face landmarks again for the new align image for cropping (to get the borders of face) ?

Comment: It's easy to calculate face landmarks again for the new align image, but it'll slow down your program. In your face alignment process, you should transform facial landmarks also using [opencv geometric transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html)

Comment: Thanks, how do I transform the landmarks ??  do you mean to say to plot them in a Mat and then use affine to rotate with same rotation as image ?

Comment: That's right. Point transform is just like image transform. Find the way to do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327659/how-can-i-remap-a-point-after-an-image-rotation

Comment: Thanks alot, that was the answer I was looking. I have another question, when resize the image after cropping (I want to resize to 160 x 170) how do you resize it without affecting ratios of the face. Iam concern since the face will stretch or shrink

Comment: To resize but not affect the ratio of the face, you should only fix 1 dimension, width or height only. You can use `resized_face= imutils.resize(face, width=160)`, `imutils` is a useful package comes from PyImageSearch. I recommend you to look at [this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/04/02/faster-facial-landmark-detector-with-dlib/), there is a bunch of dlib examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it within deepface with just a single line of code. It wraps many backends to detect faces. It also applies face alignment based on the eye locations.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
backends = ['opencv', 'ssd', 'dlib', 'mtcnn']
img = DeepFace.detectFace("img.jpg", detector_backend = backends[0])
plt.imshow(img); plt.show()
```